# SQL Server database file connected in asp.net but query not executing

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I connected a `.MDF` database file to  my aspx file in C# (Visual Studio), but when I'm trying to execute a query it doesn't work.

Given below is the code where the problem occurs. Please help me out.

The `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns -1, I guess it should return 1 in case of a successful execution

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\karunya\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Login\Login\App_Data\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

con.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE user = '"+user.Text+"' ";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
int tmp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteNonQuery());

con.Close();

if (tmp == 1)
{
    con.Open();
    sql = "SELECT pass FROM LogTable WHERE user = '" + user.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    string password = com1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (password == pass.Text)
    {
       Response.Write("Access Granted!");
    }
    else
    {
       Response.Write("Access Denied!");
    }
 }
 else
 {
    Response.Write("User Name Incorrect!");
 }
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the **number of rows** affected by a `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operation. Since you're not doing any of this, then it's always returning -1 - and this is **NOT** an error condition! [This is **ALL** nicely and extensively documented on MSDN!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you just need to **go look for it!**

Comment: In addition to @marc_s's comment, the number of affected rows is tightly dependent to the cursor type used

Comment: @Arun: I will suggest you to use executescalar if you are checking for single record. And going by your select query, it seems you are checking whether user exists. Am I right? And if you are please don't use * in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

what you trying to do ?

it will always return -1 because you are selecting tables

do this ..

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionLib))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
                {

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    conn.Close();
                    da.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

now check condition according to you if you want to check no of row then check

```
dt.rows.cout
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`, use a `COUNT(*)` inside the query and return the count using `ExecuteScalar`.

And always (ALWAYS) use parameterized queries:

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Data WHERE user = @user";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user.Text);
int tmp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

And move the call to `Close()` towards the end of the method

Answer (score 0):

please try  to  check if  the  connections string  it's  ok  then  try  this code

you  will  know if  the  select  hjas  rows  or  not  than  do what  you  want  to do

```
       con.Open();
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.CommandText = "select * from user where login=@login and pass=@psw";
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)).Value = txtpsedu.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@psw", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)).Value = txtlogin.Text;

   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.Read())
                    {

                   //// do  what  you  want  here  

                    }

                    else
                    {

                        Response.Write("User Name Incorrect!");

                    }
                    dr.Close();
                    con.Close();
```

i  hope  to  try  it